# R average date difference within two groups

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I'm working with some data with id, month, date. I'd like to have an average difference in id and for each month (so two groups). I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007677/how-to-calculate-the-average-difference-between-dates-by-id-in-r), and I've tried to modify the answer (it is made only for ID, not month), without luck.

My data are something like:

```
test <-structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
                       month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
                                3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                                3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
                                4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
                       date = structure(c(17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 
                                                                     17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 17555, 
                                                                     17555, 17579, 17579, 17579, 17579, 17579, 17579, 17579, 17579, 
                                                                     17579, 17579, 17579, 17579, 17618, 17618, 17618, 17618, 17618, 
                                                                     17618, 17618, 17618, 17618, 17618, 17618, 17621, 17621, 17621, 
                                                                      17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17621, 17649, 
                                                                      17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 
                                                                      17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 
                                                                      17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 
                                                                      17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 
                                                                      17649, 17649, 17649, 17649, 17649), class = "Date")),class="data.frame",row.names = c(NA,-98L))
```

And the result is something like(sorry for the `dput()`, but it was the less painful way to share the example of the data).

```
head(test)
id month       date
1  1     1 2018-01-24
2  1     1 2018-01-24
3  1     1 2018-01-24
4  1     1 2018-01-24
5  1     1 2018-01-24
6  1     1 2018-01-24
```

So I've tried this:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
group_by(id,month)%>%
arrange(date) %>%
summarize(avg = as.numeric(mean(diff(date))))%>%data.frame()
```

And the result is:

```
> result
  id month       avg
1  1     1 0.0000000
2  1     2 0.0000000
3  1     3 0.1428571
4  1     4 0.0000000
```

But, looking at the data, March has a problem, because the days of March are the 31 and 28, their difference is 3, and the average of that difference should be 3 (only one distance).

```
> table(test[which(test$month==3),]$date)

2018-03-28 2018-03-31 
        11         11
```

What Am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What result do you expect for each month? The average value of the difference between the average date (March 29) and the actual date? Can you list the values you'd expect for months 1-4?

Comment: Try `test %>% group_by(id, month) %>% arrange(date)  %>% distinct %>% summarise(avg = as.numeric(mean(diff(date))))`

Comment: Hi, I'd like to have `sum(Differences In Month)/Number of Differences`: for  example January, February, April, 0/0 == NaN, for March 3/1==3.

Comment: Pretty awesome @akrun, it seems working, let me test it a bit more. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you obtained is correct: `diff(date)` computes the difference between all pairs of consecutive dates in the data (within the groups and after you have sorted the dates). In March, you have 11 times `2018-03-28` and 11 times `2018-03-31`. So in March, `diff(date)` is 10 times 0, one time 3, and 10 times 0. Thus the average is 3/21=0.143.

Maybe you first want to consider distinct combinations of `(id, month, date)`:

```
test %>%
  distinct(id, month, date) %>%
  group_by(id,month)%>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  summarize(avg = as.numeric(mean(diff(date)))) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Note that this outputs 3 for March, but `NaN` for the other months since you are asking for the `diff` on a vector of length 1, which gives a vector of length 0. As an alternative, you can use

```
test %>%
  distinct(id, month, date) %>%
  group_by(id,month)%>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  summarize(avg = as.numeric(max(date)-min(date)) / max(1, n()-1))
```